# How can I make a HTTP request in using browser developer tools?

Tags: https, request, google-developers-console

I'm currently working on a web project where I need to interact with an external API to fetch data and display it on my website. To achieve this, I want to make an HTTP request directly from the browser's developer tools, without relying on any server-side code or any Programming languages. My preferred browser for development is Google Chrome, and I'm using the Chrome Developer Tools.

I've been trying to find a way to accomplish this, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm familiar with using developer tools for inspecting elements and debugging JavaScript, but I haven't used them for making HTTP requests.

I tried to run this code in Chrome Developer Console:

```
// I've tried running this code in the Chrome Developer Console
fetch('https://api.example.com/data')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
```

However, when I run this code, I encounter a CORS-related error, and the request is blocked due to cross-origin restrictions.

Is there a way to bypass these CORS restrictions or another method I can use to make an HTTP request from the browser's developer tools? I'd appreciate any guidance or alternative approaches to achieve my goal.

I expecting the most suitable way to do this using Chrome Developer tools.